# With clause does not work as expected in Oracle Database

Tags: python, sql, oracle, pypika

I'm using pypika to build some queries. It used to work great but I have an issue with subqueries on an oracle database. The query reads as follow

```
fake_query = Query().from_(my_table).where(my_table.ID == "12345").select(my_table.ID)

QN = AliasedQuery("fake_query_with")

query = (
    Query()
    .with_(fake_query, "fake_query_with")
    .from_(QN)
    .select(
        QN.star. # problematic line
    )
)

df_temp = claim_conn.read_dataframe(query.get_sql())
```

So when I run the script, I got an error:

```
DatabaseError: ORA-00904: "fake_query_with": invalid identifier
```

The pypika query is translated as expected as the string

```
WITH fake_query_with AS 
(
   SELECT "ID" 
   FROM "MYTABLE" 
   WHERE "ID"=12345
) 
SELECT "fake_query_with".* 
FROM fake_query_with
```

So this query fails, but if I replace `QN.star` by simply `*`, it works, but of course I loose the interesting usage of the alias. I know this is just a dummy snippet but the it is just to demonstrate the error.

Comment: So what is the question? The last select isn't valid due to fake_query_with not having an alias, `SELECT t.* FROM fake_query_with t` would be valid

Comment: This should be raised as an issue in the PyPika project, because `with` alias is not quoted and its usage in the `from` clause is not quoted also, while `AliasedQuery.star` returns quoted alias (as of [current source code](https://pypika.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pypika/terms.html#Star)). I didn't dig deep enough to discover their quoting strategy, but as long as other identifiers (even uppercased words, that do not require qoutes) are quoted, it looks as an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @astentx said in a comment, this looks like a bug in PyPika.

You could (probably) work around it by making the name uppercase in your code - i.e. `"FAKE_QUERY_WITH"` in both places.

```
QN = AliasedQuery("FAKE_QUERY_WITH")

query = (
    Query()
    .with_(fake_query, "FAKE_QUERY_WITH")
    .from_(QN)
    .select(
        QN.star. # problematic line
    )
)
```

Then the generated SQL should look like:

```
WITH FAKE_QUERY_WITH AS 
(
   SELECT "ID" 
   FROM "MYTABLE" 
   WHERE "ID"=12345
) 
SELECT "FAKE_QUERY_WITH".* 
FROM FAKE_QUERY_WITH
```

and the distinction between the [quoted and unquoted identifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html#GUID-75337742-67FD-4EC0-985F-741C93D918DA) will be moot.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mvfxeSHv) showing that modified SQL works - untested in PyPika but hopefully that is actually what it will generate...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Python nor Pypika, but - from Oracle's point of view - this is what's wrong here: usage of (evil!) double quotes.

In Oracle, by default, all "identifiers" (table names, column names, procedures, functions ...) are stored into the data dictionary in UPPERCASE. Then, you can reference them any way you want: UPPER, lower or MIxeD CaSe - no difference, everything will work.

But, if you enclose names into double quotes, then you **must** use double quotes every time, following the same letter case you used while creating that object - otherwise, it won't work.

For example:

```
SQL> create table mytable as
  2    select 12345 id,
  3           'Littlefoot' "NamE"
  4  from dual;

Table created.

SQL> select table_name from user_tables where table_name = 'MYTABLE';

TABLE_NAME
------------------------------
MYTABLE                            --> stored in UPPERCASE

SQL> select column_name from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'MYTABLE';

COLUMN_NAME
------------------------------ 
ID                                --> stored in UPPERCASE because there were no double quotes
NamE                              --> mixed case, as I enclosed the name into double quotes

SQL> select id from mytable;      --> reference it any way you want

        ID
----------
     12345

SQL> select name from mytable;    --> reference it exactly as it was created
select name from mytable
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "NAME": invalid identifier


SQL> select "NamE" from mytable;

NamE
----------
Littlefoot

SQL>
```

---

In your case:

```
SQL> WITH fake_query_with AS         --> CTE named using lower case, but no double quotes
  2  (
  3     SELECT "ID"
  4     FROM "MYTABLE"
  5     WHERE "ID"=12345
  6  )
  7  SELECT "fake_query_with".*      --> double quotes, lower case
  8  FROM fake_query_with;
SELECT "fake_query_with".*      
                         *
ERROR at line 7:
ORA-00904: "fake_query_with": invalid identifier


SQL>
```

If you want to make it work, then either **a)** get rid of double quotes (if you can; maybe Py* requires them, can't tell)  (that's my sincere suggestion) or **b)** use double quotes *everywhere*:

**a) no double quotes**

```
SQL> WITH
  2     fake_query_with
  3     AS
  4        (SELECT id
  5           FROM mytable
  6          WHERE id = 12345)
  7  SELECT fake_query_with.*
  8    FROM fake_query_with;

        ID
----------
     12345

SQL>
```

**b) double quotes, everywhere**

```
SQL> WITH
  2     "fake_query_with"
  3     AS
  4        (SELECT "ID"
  5           FROM "MYTABLE"
  6          WHERE "ID" = 12345)
  7  SELECT "fake_query_with".*
  8    FROM "fake_query_with";

        ID
----------
     12345

SQL>
```

See if it helps.